# postfix forward throttling

Tags: postfix

I have some problem with throttling for my mail system.

main.cf

```
initial_destination_concurrency       = 1
default_destination_concurrency_limit = 1
default_destination_recipient_limit   = 2
default_destination_rate_delay        = 1m
```

When I send mails from my site all forking fine - delay working.

/etc/aliases

```
adminuser: <mail1@domain> <mail2@domain> <mail3@domain>
```

When email forwarding for user adminuser delay not working.